# Как правильно сделать генерацию случайных чисел внутри процедуры?

Tags: c#

Выдает одинаковые значения:

```
    static void As()
    {
        Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(r.Next(-100, 100)));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        As();
        As();
        As();
        As();
        As();
        Thread.Sleep(20000);
    }
```

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Инициализировать рандом только 1 раз перед использованием методов

Comment: @yolosora static Random Rand => new Random(); так? тот же результат получается

Comment: В мейне до вызова методов, конвертить в строку тоже не обязательно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно вынести инициализацию счетчика рандома в поле класса, чтобы он не инициализировался каждый раз при вызове метода `As()`, а только один раз.

Примерно так:

```
static Random r = new Random();

static void As()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(r.Next(-100, 100)));
}
```